# How to remove Object is possibly 'null' TS2531 warning when using PropTypes.InferProps and default parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I have a simple React component that adds two numbers together. It's written in TypeScript and using @types/prop-types.

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const AddPropsTypes = {
  first: PropTypes.number,
  second: PropTypes.number
};

type Props = PropTypes.InferProps<typeof AddPropsTypes>;
const Add: React.FC<Props> = ({ first = 1, second = 2 }) => {
  return <div>{first + second}</div>;
};

Add.propTypes = AddPropsTypes;

export default Add;
```

Typescript complains that `first` and `second` could possibly be 'null' ts(2531), but they have default parameter values.

Making these `PropTypes.number.isRequired` will obviously make the warning go away, but I don't want them required.

I know I can make this warning go away with `<div>{(first || 1) + (second || 2)}</div>` within the jsx, but I shouldn't have to define the default values twice. Currently, I'm ignoring the warning with the following above the line:

```js
{/* lol https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27552
// @ts-ignore */}
```

Is there any way to define the `PropTypes` or `InferProps` so it knows about the default parameter values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non null assertion operator `!`

`first! +second!`

Comment: Thanks! I had to turn off "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion" rule, but I'm totally cool with that.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see that there is no type defined for array function arguments

```
const Add: React.FC<Props> = ({ first = 1, second = 2 }) => {
  return <div>{first + second}</div>;
};
```

How about

```
const Add: React.FC<Props> = ({ first = 1, second = 2 }: Props) => {
  return <div>{first + second}</div>;
};
```

or

```
const Add: React.FC<Props> = ({ first = 1, second = 2 }: {
  first: PropTypes.number,
  second: PropTypes.number
}) => {
  return <div>{first + second}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a super duper mage extra annoying thing with proptypes combined with typescript.  the only workaround I got is to use `"strictNullChecks": false` but this essentially means you treat don't treat null cases.